# I want to create a metabox under custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I have a custom post type and A custom Taxonomy under the post type. But I want to add a metaboxes under the custom Taxonomy. My code is not working, Please can you help.

**Working Code**

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function create_book_cpt() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Books', 'Post Type General Name', 'Books' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Book', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'Books' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'Books', 'Books' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Books', 'Books' ),
    'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'Books' ),
    'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'Books' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'Books' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'All Books', 'Books' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Book', 'Books' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'Books' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'New Book', 'Books' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Book', 'Books' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Update Book', 'Books' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'View Book', 'Books' ),
    'view_items'            => __( 'View Books', 'Books' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Search Books', 'Books' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'Books' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'Books' ),
    'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'Books' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'Books' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'Books' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'Books' ),
    'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into Book', 'Books' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this Book', 'Books' ),
    'items_list'            => __( 'Books list', 'Books' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Books list navigation', 'Books' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter Books list', 'Books' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Book', 'Books' ),
    'description'           => __( 'Open Books', 'Books' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'menu_icon'=>'dashicons-editor-video',
    'supports'              => array( 'title'),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'post',
);
register_post_type( 'Book', $args );}
  add_action( 'init', 'create_Book_cpt', 0 );

     function add_Book_series_taxonomy(){

$labels = array(
    'name'               => 'Series',
    'singular_name'      => 'Series',
    'search_items'       => 'Search Series',
    'all_items'          => 'All Series',
    'update_item'        => 'Update Series',
    'edit_item'          => 'Edit Series',
    'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Series',
    'new_item_name'      => 'New Series Name',
    'menu_name'          => 'Series'
);

//define arguments to be used
$args = array(
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'how_in_nav_menus'  => true,
    'public'            => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'Series')
);

//call the register_taxonomy function
register_taxonomy('Series', 'Book', $args);}
     add_action('init','add_Book_series_taxonomy');
```

**Not Working**

```
function add_Book_series_metabox()
 {
   add_meta_box("series_details",'Series 
   Details','Book_series_details','Series');
   }

  function Book_series_details($term)
   {
     wp_nonce_field('open_Book_save_series_meta','open_Book_details_nonce');

      $term_meta = get_option($term->id,'_Book_series_value',true);

     ?>
      <label for="series_details"> Series Details</label>
     <input type="text" id="series_details" name="series_details" value="<? 
       php _e($term_meta,'Book') ?>">

      <?php

        }
       add_action('add_meta_boxes','add_Book_series_metabox');
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by using this function

```
add_action( 'series_add_form_fields', 'sermon_series_add_details', 10, 2 );
```

instead of this:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes','add_Book_series_metabox');
```